# For each row of a numpy array, set specific elements to n

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2d array `arr`. Here's an example:

```
>> arr
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11]])
```

I also have a 2d array of indices `indices` (with `indices.shape[0] == arr.shape[0]`, and `indices.shape[1] <= arr.shape[1]`). Here is an example:

```
>>> indices
array([[0, 1],
       [1, 2],
       [0, 2],
       [0, 2]])
```

Now, I want to set some elements of `arr` to -1. Specifically, on the first row of `arr`, the first and the second element should be set to -1 (because `indices[0] == [0, 1]`). On the second row of `arr`, the second and the third element should be set to -1 (because `indices[1] == [1, 2]`). And so on.

This would be the expected result:

```
array([[ -1, -1,  2],
       [  3, -1, -1],
       [ -1,  7, -1],
       [ -1, 10, -1]])
```

I tried to look for existing solutions but I haven't found any. Any suggestion?

Comment: `np.put_along_axis(arr, indices, values=-1, axis=1)`, slightly slower than advanced indexing but perhaps more readable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Broadcast assignment:

```
>>> arr[np.arange(4)[:, None], indices] = -1
>>> arr
array([[-1, -1,  2],
       [ 3, -1, -1],
       [-1,  7, -1],
       [-1, 10, -1]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a for loop:

```py
for arow, irow in zip(arr, indices):
    for i in irow:
        arow[i] = -1
print(arr)
```

Or, in one line:

```py
new_arr = np.array([[-1 if i in irow else arow[i] for i in range(len(arow))] for arow, irow in zip(arr, indices)])
print(new_arr)
```

Output:

```py
[[-1 -1  2]
 [ 3 -1 -1]
 [-1  7 -1]
 [-1 10 -1]]
```

Comment: Thanks. Sure a for loop would work, but I'd prefer a NumPy solution, as this could be pretty slow